# Is PHP Mail Function Best For a Big Project?

Tags: php, phpmailer, swiftmailer

Thanks for attention.I just need to know is `mail()` function best and secure for big a project. Project consist on subscriptions, confirmation process etc .Many developers use `PHPMailer` and `SwiftMailer` . What is really big difference between them.if php `mail()` function best then tell the reason why ?

Your answer will be highly appreciated

Comment: Libraries are easier if you're sending anything more complex that plain text e-mails. Depending on how "big" the project is, it's also worth considering external e-mail providers like SES or Mailchimp etc if delivery is high importance.

Comment: Depends on what you're doing: `mail()` is fine for simple *"operational"* emails (*"Thank your for your order"* and so on) and `PHPMailer` is pretty much just a fancy wrapper to make life easier ... *but* `mail()` is not the right tool for mass-mailings (e.g. newsletters) - you'd want a dedicated IMAP server or a third-party mail service provider for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHPMailer or Swiftmailer just take care of everything you have to take care of when you're sending an e-mail. You could use mail() for that but you'd have to do this all by yourself. Setting the right headers for example. Or composing an HTML-mail.

mailer-classes are just a much more comfortable way to send e-mails and you can be sure not to get marked as spam or anything like that. I'd rely on one anytime.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev As a developer, absolutely! As somebody that needs e-mail, hell no! ;P

Comment: sure is probably a little bit strong, but you can be much more sure than when you use pure mail().

Comment: I'd also add that the PHP mail() function is inherently insecure, and is also unsafe. It's both safer and faster to use SMTP to localhost, which you can't do using the mail function.